# How to add custom tab in ribbon in microsoft office power point 2011 Mac Edition?

Tags: applescript, powerpoint, ribbon

I need to add custom tab in ribbon. Actually its already implemented in Windows MS powerpoint using vb. But how can i implement custom ribbon in MAC Edition Power point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Mac PPT doesn't allow ribbon customization.
You'll need to provide user interface using the old-style commandbars.

Comment: Oh. ok. steve can we create custom task pane in mac powerpoint ?

Comment: Not that I know of.  I don't believe it's possible.